# Trying to create a test class for Httpcallout but getting error Illegal assignment from void to System.HttpResponse

Tags: unit-test, community, salesforce-id

Could you please help me with this test class?

I am using Genderized API to populate the custom filed on Lead name gender (Gender__C).

API Link - https://api.genderize.io/?name=peter

1. Get_Gender_Lead - Class

```java
public class Get_Gender_Lead {
    
    @Future(callout=true)
    public static void GetGender(Set<id> setids)
    {
        String GetGender='';
        List<Lead> leads = new List<Lead>();
        leads =[select name,gender__c,FirstName from Lead where id in :setids];
        if(leads.size()>0)
        {
            for(Lead lead : leads)
                
            {
                String fcmlink='https://api.genderize.io/?name='+lead.FirstName;
                Http http = new Http();
                HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
                request.setEndpoint(fcmlink);
                
                request.setMethod('GET');
                HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
                Map<String, Object> deserialized = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());
                if(deserialized!=null )
                {
                    GetGender=   String.valueof(deserialized.get('gender'));
                }
                lead.Gender__c=GetGender;
                
            }
            update Leads;
            Recursive.Runonce=false;
            
        }
    }
    
}
```

2. Recursive class

```java
global class Recursive {
        public static boolean Runonce =true;
}
```

3. Trigger on lead

```java
trigger LeadTrigger on Lead (After insert , After update) {

      if(Recursive.Runonce==true && System.isFuture()!=true)
        Get_Gender_Lead.GetGender(trigger.newmap.keyset());
    
}
```

4. GenderCalloutMockTest

```java
@isTest
Global class GenderCalloutMockTest implements HttpCalloutMock  {
    global HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest request) {
         System.assertEquals('https://api.genderize.io/?name=peter', request.getEndpoint());
        System.assertEquals('GET', request.getMethod());
        // Create a fake response
        HttpResponse response = new HttpResponse();
        response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        response.setBody('{"name":"peter","gender":"male","probability":0.99,"count":165452}');
        //{"name":"peter","gender":"male","probability":0.99,"count":165452}
        response.setStatusCode(200);
        return response; 
}
}
```

5. GenderCalloutTest

```java
@isTest
public class GenderCalloutTest {

    @isTest static Void testGetCallout() {
        Set<id> setids = new set<id>();
              
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new GenderCalloutMockTest());
        // Call method to test
        HttpResponse result = Get_Gender_Lead.GetGender(setids);
              
        String contentType = result.getHeader('Content-Type');
        System.assert(contentType == 'application/json');
        String expectedValue = '{"name":"peter","gender":"male","probability":0.99,"count":165452}';
        String actualValue = result.getBody();
        System.assertEquals(actualValue, expectedValue);
        System.assertEquals(200, result.getStatusCode());
        System.debug(actualValue);
        System.debug(expectedValue);
       
    }
}
```

I am facing an error in 5. GenderCalloutTest as it is giving "Illegal assignment from void to System.HttpResponse".

Thank you

Comment: Your ```GetGender``` does not return anything, while in the test class you try to assign result of that method to ```result``` variable (```HttpResponse result = Get_Gender_Lead.GetGender(setids);```). That is what given error means

Comment: Hello @kurunve thank you for the explanation, Could you please help me with the code that what do I need to change to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The test is trying to use the HttpResponse, but the GetGender only returns void.  To avoid changing your implementation, you should change the test.

The test should start, insert a lead, do the mock callout, then check that the lead is updated.  IE: you should be testing the business result (an updated lead), not the HTTPResponse headers and values.

An alternative was mentioned in the comments.  You could change GetGender to return an HTTPResponse so you can inspect it.  But that would change the core logic for no other purpose than testing.  If you must, line 4 would be:

```
public static HTTPResponse GetGender(Set<id> setids)
```